# How to fix wrongly positioned draggable helpers for connected sortables (partially caused by floated/relative positioned parent elements)?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

### Preface

I'm experiencing a problem where the draggable helper is being offset incorrectly, when using draggables + sortables that are placed in floating, relative positioned parent elements. The floated parent elements are Bootstrap columns, where multiple sortable lists are placed in one column, and a list of draggables is placed in another.

### Example

Here's a working example snippet

```js
$('.sortable').sortable({
  connectWith: '.sortable',
  revert: 600,
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  placeholder: 'ui-sortable-placeholder',
  tolerance: 'pointer'
}).disableSelection();

$('.draggable').draggable({
  connectToSortable: '.sortable',
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: true
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
.sortable-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.sortable {
  cursor: move;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  background: #ff0000;
}
#draggables {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.draggable {
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: move;
  color: #fff;
  background: #5dd1ff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>bar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-6'>
      <div id='sortables'>
        <div class='sortable-container'>
          <ul class='sortable'>
            <li>sortable 1</li>
            <li>sortable 2</li>
            <li>sortable 3</li>
            <li>sortable 4</li>
            <li>sortable 5</li>
            <li>sortable 6</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='sortable-container'>
          <ul class='sortable'>
            <li>sortable 1</li>
            <li>sortable 2</li>
            <li>sortable 3</li>
            <li>sortable 4</li>
            <li>sortable 5</li>
            <li>sortable 6</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='sortable-container'>
          <ul class='sortable'>
            <li>sortable 1</li>
            <li>sortable 2</li>
            <li>sortable 3</li>
            <li>sortable 4</li>
            <li>sortable 5</li>
            <li>sortable 6</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-xs-6'>
      <ul id='draggables'>
        <li class='draggable'>draggable 1</li>
        <li class='draggable'>draggable 2</li>
        <li class='draggable'>draggable 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Update 16 Nov 2015*** I've modified the code example to better reflect my actual usage context, where there are further rows above the one that holds the draggables/sortables.

a [screencast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjLQf.gif), and a still image showing what happens

[image]

### Further explanation

When dragging one of the draggables from right hand side column over one of the sortable lists on the left hand side, and not dropping it, but dragging it further out of the sortable lists bounding box, the helper is being positioned incorrectly, it shifts a few hundred pixels to the left, as if it's incorrectly incorporating some kind of offset (looks like it could be the the original draggable position).

Interestingly this doesn't occur when the draggables are placed in the same parent element as the sortables, at least it won't shift horizontally, but vertically when moving the draggable fast up/down or left/right in/out of the sortable list.

The horizontal shift is somehow related to floated/relative positioned parent elements, disabling the floating or the relative positioning fixes it. However, I'd like to keep this as is, and find another fix/workaround instead. The vertical shifting also happens when floating/relative positioning isn't involved, so I guess there's a little more to this problem.

***Update 15 Nov 2015* - jQuery UI changes**

Looks like jQuery UI 1.11.4 changed the behavior a little, now it won't immediately shift horizontally the moment you leave the bounding box of a sortable, but you have to move between two or more sortables first. Other than that, the buggy behavior seems to be unchanged.

***Update 16 Nov 2015* - `appendTo` option**

Initially I've tried to use `appendTo` a workaround, as that way the helper would be kept outside of the lists, and while this is true for my original example code, it won't work with the updated example code, where further rows are placed above the ones that holds the draggables/sortables, they are causing the helper to shift vertically.

### Question

Does anyone know where the problematic horizontal offset stems from exactly, and how to fix it while keep using floated/relative positioned parent elements?

And what about the vertical offsetting, seeing that this happens in [**the jQuery UI demo**](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable) too, makes me think that this is a bug that isn't related to the styling of parent elements?

***Update 15 Nov 2015* - Vertical offset problem located**

The vertical offset seems to have to do with the margin applied on the draggables, without that it seems to work fine.

I've reported both as bugs, but I'm still looking for a fix/workaround that I can apply myself until this may or may not be fixed in the library.

**http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/14822**
**http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/14806**

Comment: You want to implement the dragged and sort-able like WordPress admin menu functionality?

Comment: @Mitul I'm not sure know what exactly you are referring to, but the actual context is a calendar-ish application, where predefined elements can be dragged into days that consist of multiple predefined segments (sortables). However this shouldn't really matter, in the end it's just about draggables and sortables in separate floated elements, as I need to keep this structure.

Comment: Can you show me what is the expected output after you will drag the element. I have see your screen the last part show me the draggable3 element at bellow of the three sortable elements so you want to show draggable element over there?

Comment: @Mitul The expected result is the draggable helper being kept under the pointer while dragging, and finally being placed in the sortable (this can happen one or mutliple times per draggable, depending on what it represents in the app) once you actually drop it. The latter works fine (see the working example), the only problem is that the helper is being misplaced during the drag operation. ps, have to leave for the night, I can answer further questions tomorrow.

Comment: I have had exactly the same problem. ended up just using another approach, since it was too buggy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is strange is that it seems to work better with **jquery-ui 10.4**. The difference is that in 10.4 the **draggable helper** stays in its original div, and is cloned into the sortables but hidden. So calculations are easier to make.

In 11.4, the **helper** is appended to the sortable over which it is dragged, which makes the precise offset calculations hard to follow. You constantly have to change the parent offset, and keep track of over which sortable it is, over which sortable it was, the position of the sortable and so on. And clearly there is a bug there.

One simple solution would be to get the **connectToSortable** plugin from 10.4. You'll have to check for unwanted side effects, but quickly it seems to be working. You can use a different name so that you keep the original. Like this:

```
$.ui.plugin.add("draggable", "connectToSortable104", {
    // You take the whole connectToSortable plugin from  
    // here: https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js  
    // In 11.4 you'll need to add draggable parameter 
    // for example: to the event methods,
    // start: function(event, ui, draggable)
    ...
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/gsnojkbc/2/

EDIT:

I don't think the additional div is what causes the problem, it's really a bug with the way the **connectToSortable** works in jquery 11.4 that is causing the issue. To allow moving the helper in the **sortables** and still keep track of the proper offset, you need to readjust some data each time the helper changes div. There's two flaws in the way it's done:

First one is that there's a **refreshOffsets** method that is common to
   other events in **draggable**. It's used for example when you click on a
   draggable. And so it tries to calculate the offset based on the
   click. But when calling **refreshOffsets** from the sortable event, it
   messes the click offset. This can be solved by changing
   **refreshOffsets** method so as not to consider the **event.pageX** and Y.
   Like this:

```
$.ui.draggable.prototype._refreshOffsetsSortable = function(event, draggable){

        this.offset = {
                top: this.positionAbs.top - this.margins.top,
                left: this.positionAbs.left - this.margins.left,
                scroll: false,
                parent: this._getParentOffset(),
                relative: this._getRelativeOffset()
            };

            this.offset.click = draggable.offset.click;
    }
```

The other problem happens because you have many **sortables**. Basically
   the other operation that needs to be done is change the parent
   offset. The way it's done right now is that it saves the previous
   parent. Normally it works but if you move too fast, the sequence
   makes it so that the saved parent is a **sortable** and not the original
   parent. You can fix this by saving the parent on drag start, which in
   any case makes seems to make more sense. Like this:

```
$.ui.plugin.add( "draggable", "connectToSortableFixed", {
    start: function( event, ui, draggable ) {
        var uiSortable = $.extend( {}, ui, {
            item: draggable.element
        });
        draggable._parent = this.parent();
...
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/24a8q49j/1/

Comment: Now that's an interesting observation. The first thing I tried to workaround this problem, was to use the `appendTo` option so that the helper is kept outside of the lists, but it wasn't working, the helper was still being misplaced. I've now tried it with my and your example, and it seems to work just fine. I'll have to check back if there is more to this in my app context when I'm home at my machine.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue with `appendTo`, in my app there are more rows above (I'll update my example code), which causes the helper to shift vertically. Further tests show that it also will shift horizontally again when the whole thing itself is nested in a further row/column (not the case in my app though). However it seems that appending to the sortable container (`#sortables`) works, but I'll have to do further tests. For the time being, please take my upvote, your suggestion seems to work fine too, and led me to the possible `appendTo` workaround :)

Comment: Thanks for the further insight, this gives me a good idea as to what actually happens in the core :) As for the additional divs (rows), I didn't mean to say that they are responsible for the overall problem, just that the buggy behavior is affected by them when using the `appendTo` option.

Answer (score 5):

A simple JavaScript only workaround is to store the offset to the mouse when the dragging starts and then force the `ui.helper` to have the same offset to the mouse - always:

```
[...]
var offset_start = {};

$('.draggable').draggable({
  connectToSortable: '.sortable',
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: true,
  start: function(e, ui) {
      offset_start = {
          x: ui.position.left - e.pageX,
          y: ui.position.top - e.pageY
      }
  },
  drag: function(e, ui) {
      ui.position.top = e.pageY + offset_start.y
      ui.position.left = e.pageX + offset_start.x
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

See the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uL36p01n/).

For the simple case this is an easy workaround, but requires more work if you introduce borders (where the helper cannot leave) etc.

---

Edit: For your snippet I came up with another solution (because the other one does not work as expected - harder to get the initial offsets than I thought ...): Simply force the item to stay at the mouse pointer regardless of the initial offset after appending the helper to the body. It is not 100% nice, because when starting to drag it might "jump" to the mouse - but then it stays there at least ...

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
  connectToSortable: '.sortable',
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: 'invalid',
  appendTo: 'body',
  drag: function(e, ui) {
    if (!ui.helper.parent().is('body')) {
      ui.helper.appendTo($('body'));
    }
    ui.position.top = e.pageY - 10;
    ui.position.left = e.pageX - 25;
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

```js
$('.sortable').sortable({
  connectWith: '.sortable',
  revert: 600,
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  placeholder: 'ui-sortable-placeholder',
  tolerance: 'pointer'
}).disableSelection();


$('.draggable').draggable({
  connectToSortable: '.sortable',
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: 'invalid',
  appendTo: 'body',
  scroll: false,
  drag: function(e, ui) {
    if (!ui.helper.parent().is('body')) {
      ui.helper.appendTo($('body'));
    }
    ui.position.top = e.pageY - 15;
    ui.position.left = e.pageX - 25;
  }
}).disableSelection()
```

```css
.sortable-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.sortable {
  cursor: move;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  background: #ff0000;
}
#draggables {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.draggable {
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: move;
  color: #fff;
  background: #5dd1ff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>bar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-6'>
      <div id='sortables'>
        <div class='sortable-container'>
          <ul class='sortable'>
            <li>sortable 1</li>
            <li>sortable 2</li>
            <li>sortable 3</li>
            <li>sortable 4</li>
            <li>sortable 5</li>
            <li>sortable 6</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='sortable-container'>
          <ul class='sortable'>
            <li>sortable 1</li>
            <li>sortable 2</li>
            <li>sortable 3</li>
            <li>sortable 4</li>
            <li>sortable 5</li>
            <li>sortable 6</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='sortable-container'>
          <ul class='sortable'>
            <li>sortable 1</li>
            <li>sortable 2</li>
            <li>sortable 3</li>
            <li>sortable 4</li>
            <li>sortable 5</li>
            <li>sortable 6</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-xs-6'>
      <ul id='draggables'>
        <li class='draggable'>draggable 1</li>
        <li class='draggable'>draggable 2</li>
        <li class='draggable'>draggable 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a neat trick, and looks like a possible workaround in case `appendTo`-only won't work... speaking of `appendTo`, additionally using `appendTo: 'body'` fixes the incorrect draggable revert (not the "back and forth" when dropping into the list, but just the "back to the draggables").

Comment: Good catch, I added the option. And now simply sell the back and forth animation when dropping onto a list as a cool feature to your users (*it's not a bug, it's a feature*), and everybody is happy ;-) (until it is fixed upstream)

Comment: I added `revert: 'invalid'` - now it does not jump back and forth anymore - *edit*: well, at least sometimes ... ;-) (doesn't look like jqueryUI's draggable is the stablest and deterministic plugin of all)

Comment: Yeah, it's indeed pretty unstable... Initially I tried to handle revert on my own with a callback as `invalid` wasn't working as expected, and I noticed that that the argument passed to the function, which should be a reference to the drop target on a successful drop, was pretty often `false` when moving a little faster from one list to another, so that's another bug report I guess.

Answer (score 1):

see https://jsfiddle.net/tsLcjw9c/1/

I put a fixed width on the draggables list (100px) so that the draggable helper has the same width as the list items, this prevents the initial horizontal offset.

the big horizontal offset you got while dragging over the sortable container indeed seems to be a bug in jquery UI but it also seems to be exactly 100% of the width of the sortable container, which is why I added the following css:

```
.sortable .ui-draggable-dragging:not(.ui-sortable-helper){
    margin-left:100%;
}
```

The vertical offset that you got after entering and leaving the sortable lists seemed to be caused by the draggable items' margin of 4px, which I removed. You can reach the same effect with a transparent border and box-sizing:border-box; or either add a padding and set background-clip to padding-box.

Lastly the 600ms animation that you wanted to happen upon dropping the items happened in a strange way in my browser (Chrome), it went to 2 different locations before finally animating towards the correct place. This is why I now disabled the animation. You can try to override the drop event in the sortable jQuery, so that you manually animate towards the correct location.

Here the jsfiddle code:

html

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-6'>
      <div id='sortables'>
        <div class='sortable-container'>
          <ul class='sortable'>
            <li>sortable 1</li>
            <li>sortable 2</li>
            <li>sortable 3</li>
            <li>sortable 4</li>
            <li>sortable 5</li>
            <li>sortable 6</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='sortable-container'>
          <ul class='sortable'>
            <li>sortable 1</li>
            <li>sortable 2</li>
            <li>sortable 3</li>
            <li>sortable 4</li>
            <li>sortable 5</li>
            <li>sortable 6</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='sortable-container'>
          <ul class='sortable'>
            <li>sortable 1</li>
            <li>sortable 2</li>
            <li>sortable 3</li>
            <li>sortable 4</li>
            <li>sortable 5</li>
            <li>sortable 6</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-xs-6'>
      <ul id='draggables'>
        <li class='draggable'>draggable 1</li>
        <li class='draggable'>draggable 2</li>
        <li class='draggable'>draggable 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
  connectWith: '.sortable',
  revert: 0,
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  placeholder: 'ui-sortable-placeholder',
  tolerance: 'pointer'
}).disableSelection();

$('.draggable').draggable({
  connectToSortable: '.sortable',
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: false
}).disableSelection();
```

css

```
.sortable-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.sortable {
  cursor: move;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  background: #ff0000;
}
#draggables {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.draggable {
  cursor: move;
  color: #fff;
  background: #5dd1ff;
    width:100px;
    max-width:100%;
}
.sortable .ui-draggable-dragging:not(.ui-sortable-helper){
    margin-left:100%;
}
```

Comment: What "_initial offset_" are you referring to? The draggable/helper width doesn't seem to have anything to do with any offset, at least not in my tests. The 100% margin workaround unfortunately doesn't seem too work reliably, with this applied, the helper will sometimes being shifted in the other direction, ie to the right (**http://i.imgur.com/0uiZv3k.gif**).

Comment: hmm, i guess i didn't test thoroughly enough. The initial offset I was referring to was because when i run the code, the draggable list items are wide (block display) and upon dragging the handler is the width of the text which is why it gets an offset, because the widths arent the same