# jquery ui Sortable element drop shows when outside the box

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have 3 colums with sortable, while they are dragged from a menu items box, While the drag and drop works perfectly, the issue with sortable is,when I try to drag a dropped block, the sortable drop is done only when I drag the element left of the container where I want to drop it.
Can anyone please help me out with this.

HTML:

```
<div class="row page-layout">
        <div class="col-sm-9" id="droppable-container">
            <div class="droppable" id="droppable1"></div>
            <div class=" droppable" id="droppable2"></div>
            <div class=" droppable" id="droppable3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="draggable">
            <div class="draggable-item text-item">
                <span class="edit-icon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
                <span class="delete-icon"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="draggable-item image-item">
                <span class="edit-icon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
                <span class="delete-icon"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
                <p>Image</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(".draggable-item").draggable({
    connectToSortable: '.droppable',
    helper: 'clone'
})


$("#droppable1").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    connectWith: "#droppable1,#droppable2,#droppable3"
});
$("#droppable2").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    connectWith: "#droppable1,#droppable2,#droppable3"
});
$("#droppable3").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    connectWith: "#droppable1,#droppable2,#droppable3"
});
```

The fiddle link is: https://jsfiddle.net/anubala/0h1unoL7/

[image: Screenshot of fiddle while sorting]

Comment: Interesting, if you omit the `helper: 'clone'` part it works. Haven't worked with jquery ui sortable yet so I don't know why that's an issue.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683926/how-to-fix-wrongly-positioned-draggable-helpers-for-connected-sortables-partial) can help you, I particularly could not understand why this is happening, I saw people saying it's a bug.

Comment: Thank  you so much

Answer (score 0):

what I see that there is a conflict with the naming the js see only the last class I will suggest to changing `connectToSortable : '#droppable1,#droppable2,#droppable3'`